# Get input$id from cloned shinyjqui objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny, jquery-ui-droppable

This is a pretty specific example which I've tried to pair down as much as possible, but I have created draggable divs using `shinyjqui` with a selectInput box. The issue is that using `input$id` gives me the selectInput in the original drag area, and I want to get all the `input$ids` of the boxes dragged into the drop zone.

I think the best approach would be to add JQuery code that reassigns the ids of the dropped elements so I can access their inputs - does anyone have any idea how to best approach this problem?

## Current Output

#### Using `make.unique` to give each `input$dest_order$text` a number, I was hoping I could then dynamically create selectInput ids that match these so I can use what I've pasted into the `input` column to get the actual select values? This may not be the best approach and I'm open to entirely different suggestions!!!

[image]

## Desired Output

#### Instead of just `input$dropdown` which is the `selectInput` of the left hand select, My strategy is to create unique IDs for each select in the Put Here `div` so I can get the `input$dropdown.1`, `input$dropdown.2` etc etc from the right hand list, but maybe there's a way using JQuery to get all the selected options inside the `Put Here` box without needing to mess with the IDs?

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyjqui)

BLOCKS <- c("dropdown", "Block")

Blocks <- function(data, name)
{
  div(style = "
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 12px;
      background-color: #A9A9A9;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;
      min-width: 80px;
      ",
      drag = name,
      id = name,
      class = "cloned",
      if (name == "dropdown") {
        # how do I abstractly make the ids ttest_1 and ttest_2
        # based on the occurances in the vector?
        selectInput(name, "Dropdown", choices = c("1", "2", "3"), selectize = FALSE)
      } else {
        name
      }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      "$( function() {
      $( '.delete_dropped' ).droppable({
      drop: function(e, ui) {
      $(ui.helper).remove();
      }
      })
      });

      $( function() {
      $( '.cloned' ).draggable({
      helper: 'clone',
      connectToSortable: '#dest',
      drop: function(e, ui) {
      $(ui.helper).remove();
      }
      })
      });"
)),

sidebarPanel(
  fluidRow(column(6, h5("Drag"),
                  jqui_sortable(div(id = "source", class="delete_dropped",
                                    lapply(BLOCKS, Blocks, data = BLOCKS),
                                    style = "border: 1px solid black;padding:10px;min-height:50px;"),
                                options = list(connectWith = "#dest"))),
           column(6, h5("Put Here"),
                  jqui_sortable(div(id = "dest", style = "border: 1px solid black;padding:10px;min-height:50px"),
                                options = list(connectWith = "#source")))
  )),
mainPanel(tableOutput("debug"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$debug <- renderTable({
    # print the block text and make unique
    # maybe I can use these unique names to rename the ids of the selectInputs
    # then I can input[["Dropdown"]], input[["Dropdown.1"]], etc etc to get the selected option?
    t <- data.frame( id = make.unique(unlist(input$dest_order$text)))
    t$input <- ifelse(grepl('^Block', t$id), NA, paste0("input[[", t$id, "]]"))
    t
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I realize this is incredibly specific so I'd really appreciate any help, either with code or even just generally the best way to attack this problem!

Comment: Interesting question. [Here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/RH6ZA4QakZmnzPah9vpb?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=worker&utm_campaign=next&preview) might be part of the answer to it. I was not able to adapt it to your shiny app, but maybe it helps.

Comment: Whoa that's super helpful, thanks @TimTeaFan! I'll try adapting the code to my use case!

Comment: If you figure it out, please post an answer to your post, would be interesting to know how you solved it ;)